# JVM architecture: Runtime constant pool in Method area is per-class

Tags: java, jvm

By reading Oracle JVM architecture document:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html

> A run-time constant pool is a per-class or per-interface run-time
>   representation of the constant_pool table in a class file (§4.4).

I understand that for each **class**, it has a runtime constant pool (please correct me if I am wrong).

However, what I am confused is that if I have two different classes A and B and each class has a private String variable say `String value = "abc"`.

if I compare `A.value` with `B.value` using `==` rather than `equals`, I will get a `true` which make me think that `"abc"` in both A and B are in the same runtime constant pool? Could someone point me out where I am wrong ?

Comment: can you link the doc ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi linked

Comment: If they are both private, how are you accessing both at once to compare them? Does one create an instance of the other? Can you post your full code?

Comment: Off-topic : why would you want to compare strings using `==` ?

Comment: @Andrew I create instances for both classes in main and use getter to get the value.

Comment: @rkosegi I am not going to use ==, I just want to understand why this is not working and how exactly does JVM works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a preemptive optimization that the JLS superimposes.

From [JLS 7, §3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) (formatting mine)

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class `String`. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions [(§15.28)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

However, note that this is only true of String literals and constant expressions. Dynamically constructed strings (e.g. `x + y` for Strings `x` and `y`) are not automatically interned to share the same unique instances. As a result, you will still have to use `.equals` in general unless you can guarantee that your operands are constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This is because '==' is comparing references. Objects of both A and B have different String value variables (and so each class' constant pool has a separate entry for it); but they are both initialized to the same value. The compiler/JVM is most likely optimizing for space by having them both point to the same compile-time constant value in the bytecode. The '==' operator is NOT comparing constant pool locations.

Edit: to clear up some confusion, this does NOT mean that "==" can be used for string comparison. All I was saying was that it cannot be used to compare constant pool location either. It is for one thing and one thing only: comparing whether two references point to the same object. The situation in the question will SOMETIMES result in == returning true, but sometimes not. It depends on decisions the compiler and JVM make (or depending on what the JSL says as an astute answerer has said).

Comment: Does that means it is always safe to use "==" for string comparison?

Comment: @GuifanLi NO! The "==" operator compares whether two references point to the same value. If a program read the string "abc" from a file, whatever variable pointed to it would NOT == this value. They would be .equal though.